# how to apply iphone theme only for my account page?

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

Problem is we are using bootstrap for magento theme so we dont have to make a seperate theme for mobile devices.But we need to use "iphone" theme page of my account for mobile devices as its already responsive any ready to use.
Is it possible with magento?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a theme called 'myiphone' that contains only the necessary file for the iphone theme and set your theme as default. This way your new theme should fallback to your responsive theme and it will use the templates from 'myiphone' just for the customer login page.